# Get percentage differnce between two times java

Tags: java, math, time

I want to get the percentage difference between two times. I have two values one is considered to be the device I am testing and the other is considered my reference. I want to make sure that I am a certain percentage better than the reference, but the smaller the number the better. Here is what I am doing:

```
difPercent = ((dRefDif - dDutDif)/dRefDif) * 100;
```

So when the device under test is 34.695 seconds and the reference is 3.183 seconds this equation gives me -990%....is this correct? Or do I have something mixed up? It should be a negative number, I was just surprised at the percentage difference. Idk, maybe I am confusing myself. I thought this was corrct.

Comment: 34-3 ~ 31 which is about 10 times (= 1,000%) 3 so it looks right. Can you show a complete example with the input values, actual output and expected output?

Comment: That was an example the input was (3.183 - 34.695)/3.183

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 34.695 is about 10-times bigger than 3.183, I would expect the percent difference to be approaching 1000, since a 100% *increase* would be double, 200% would be triple, etc., and 900% would be 10-times. Whether you are asking the right question or in the right manner is different.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure who you're audience is, but negative percentages probably won't make as much sense.

Try:

```
(dDutDif / dRefDif) * 100
```

That way you know your Device Under Test only took less time to run if it's under 100 and more time to run if it's over 100.

Comment: I am trying to say that the larger number is a certain % worse than the smaller number as the smaller number is what is desired. For instance, if I had two ping times the shorter time would be more desired. So if this was a ping test and I wanted to compare the ping ms I would either be pos/neg compared to my reference